# What are best practices for using frames (or iframes) with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, haml

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app where people are clicking on addresses. When they click, I want to display a small google map of the address in a frame. I want to use a frame/iframe so when they scroll down to look at more addresses, the little map won't scroll off too.

I'm having a hard time finding examples or discussions of this. I was thinking of hacking up the layout with raw `<FRAMESET>` tags, but that seems kind of barbaric. What is the best way to use frames or iframes within a Rails app?

BTW, we're using Haml for our templating, if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the Greybox jQuery plugin.

Comment: Greybox looks like it's modal- I need a solution that will allow interaction in different panes concurrently. Appreciate the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You can anchor an `iframe` to the side of your page (or bottom or whatever) using CSS (`position: fixed`).  If you do that, be sure to take into consideration overlapping issues.  This is easily resolved with a margin for `body`.